# Как определить, нужно ли выделять память в даном случае? Си

Tags: c++, c, указатели, память, локальные-переменные

```
struct AB{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct AB* init_AB(){
   struct AB newAB;
   newAB.a = 1;newAB.b = 2;
   return &newAB;
}

int main(){
  struct AB* newAB = init_AB();
  printf("A:%d B:%d\n", newAB->a, newAB->b);
}
```

Вот абсолютно простой пример, пусть после printf я продолжаю использовать эту структру, просто любопытно, в какой момент времени ОС позволит зачистить эту память и моя программа упадет, как понять, нужно ли мне выделять с помощью calloc память под эту структуру или нет.

Comment: `struct AB newAB` — это локальная переменная внутри функции, а значит эта память зачищается после `return` в функции, и внутри printf вы уже НЕ МОЖЕТЕ её использовать. Если этот код работает — то только благодаря стековому чуду.

Comment: Собственно, у меня этот код и не работает — сразу падает в ошибку сегментирования, ничего не успев отпечатать.

Comment: Это компилятор волюнтаристически возвращает 0 из init_AB(). Если его немного обмануть (используя volatile size_t t = (size_t)&newAB; return (void *)t;), то падать перестанет (но 1 и 2, конечно не напечатает)

Answer (score 4):

Вы переходите перекресток на красный свет с закрытыми глазами и заткнутыми ушами.

Просто любопытно, в какой момент времени вас собьет машина и вы упадете... как понять, нужно ли вам переходить через перекресток на зеленый свет или нет?

Это - полная аналогия того, что делаете вы, и вашего вопроса. Только операционная система тут ни при чем, она не обязана "позволить зачистить" - просто ваша же программа воспользуется этим местом стековой памяти и что-нибудь туда запишет.

Естественно, если вы хотите поступать правильно, в соответствии со стандартом - вы обязаны выделять память динамически (или, например, объявив переменную как `static`). Иначе вы вступаете на скользкую дорожку неопределенного поведения - а оно на то и неопределенное, что иногда даже может сработать без неприятностей (ведь если бы неприятность гарантировалась - это было бы уже *определенное* поведение, правда?).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш собственный способ работать не будет, так как все локальные переменные *могут* передаваться через стек. И все ваши усилия будут стёрты.

Чтобы разбираться что такое стек в Си я предлагаю книжный метод, как пользоваться. А так-же метод для гуру, чтобы точно знать как всё работает.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 retsta.c -o retsta

struct AB{
    int a;
    int b;
};

// для функции уже выделено место в стеке,
//  и вы имеете право записывать результат
void  init_AB ( struct AB * pAB ) {
   pAB->a = 1;
   pAB->b = 2;
}

# include <stdint.h>

// гуру
// стек 2 для личных нужд
uint8_t stack [ 0x1000  ] ;
// аналог SP = Stack Pointer в ассебмлере
uint8_t * stackp  = & stack [ 0 ] ;

struct AB * init_ABp ( void ) {
  // место в стеке для результата
  struct AB * result = ( struct AB * ) stackp ;
  // сдвигаем стековый указатель
  stackp  +=  sizeof  ( struct AB ) ;
  result  ->  a = 1 ;
  result  ->  b = 2 ;
  return  result  ;
}

# include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  // правильный способ, выделяем место в стеке
  struct AB newAB ;
  // и передаём указатель в функцию
  init_AB ( & newAB ) ;
  printf("A:%d B:%d\n", newAB.a, newAB.b);
  // гуру
  { // запоминается точка входа стека
    uint8_t * const stackback = stackp ;
    struct AB * newABp = init_ABp  ( ) ;
    // результат храниться в личном стеке
    printf("A:%d B:%d\n", newABp->a, newABp->b);
    // здесь можно вызывать деструктор элементов в стеке
    // ..
    // восстанавливает стек
    stackp = stackback ; }
}
```