# Создание и просмотр таблицы двумерного массива в разных функциях на C++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Создал программу просмотра и создания массива в разных функциях
Не понимаю как исправить ошибки в передачи массива.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    using namespace std;

    const int Col = 4;
    const int Str = 4;

    int Create_T(int Str,int Col])
    {
      int arr[Str][Col];
      for (int i = 0; i < Col; i++) {
      for(int j= 0; i<Str;++)
      arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
      }
    return(arr);
    }

    int Watch_T(int arr[][]) 
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < Col; i++)
       {
         for (int j = 0; i < Str; ++)
         cout << arr[i][j]
       }
    }  

    int main()
    {
      int arr[Str][Col];
      SetConsoleCP(1251);
      SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
      Create_T(int Str,int Col);
      Watch_T(int arr[Str][Col]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот только что буквально спрашивали, можно ли [возвращать указатель на локальную переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1220421/195342)... Нельзя!

```
int Create_T(int Str,int Col])
{
  int arr[Str][Col];
  ....
  return(arr);
}
```

Категорически нельзя! и не получится, кстати - хотя бы потому, что согласно объявлению ваша функция возвращает `int`, а не массив...

Проще всего так:

```
int** Create_T(int Str, int Col)
{
    int ** arr = new int*[Str];
    for (int i = 0; i < Str; i++) 
    {
         arr[i] = new int[Col];
         for(int j= 0; j < Col; ++j)
             arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
    return arr;
}

void Watch_T(int **arr, int Str, int Col) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Str; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < Col; ++j)
             cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
         cout << endl;
    }
}
```

И еще - программист просто обязан быть аккуратным. Просто чтоб не позориться выражениями типа

```
for (int j = 0; i < Str; ++)
```

счетчик `j`, проверка `i`, `++` вообще ни к чему не относится. Что вы такое пишете?!

А эти вызовы -

```
  Create_T(int Str,int Col);
  Watch_T(int arr[Str][Col]);
```

Вы вообще хоть немного учебник читали? Или следующим будет - "а теперь исправьте все остальное, чтоб я сдать мог"?

Comment: Спасибо. Про счетчик торопился

Comment: А у вас что, вашего рабочего кода нет? Вы его прямо сюда писать начали? Не пытаясь компилировать?